# Local Minimum Intuition for this Question

Tags: optimization, conic-sections

If anyone could help with the intuition for solving and going about the following relative extrema problem, it would be greatly appreciated. The problem is as follows:

> Determine point(s) on $y = x^2 + 1$ that are closest to the point $(0,2)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Any point on $\,y=x^2+1\,$ will have coordinates $\,(x,x^2+1)\,$. Just write the formula for the distance from $\,(x,x^2+1)\,$ to $\,(0,2)\,$, then find the critical points.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+(x^2-1)^2}$$
we have to find the minimum:
$$h(x)=x^2+(x^2-1)^2$$
$$h'(x)=2x+2(x^2-1)2x$$
$$h'(x)=2x(2x^2-1)$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thanks a ton!